# Как в Rider настроить переносы длинных строк автоматически?

Tags: ide, jetbrains, rider

В Visual Studio 19 по умолчанию длинная строка переносится. Причем перенос этот будет виден лишь в самой Visual Studio. Таким образом, строка не выходит за пределы экрана. Пытаюсь настроить то же самое в Rider.

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C# -> Line Breaks and Wrapping -> General. Фокусируюсь на Wrap long line. Такое описание выскакивает:

```
Wrap long lines
When enabled:
string output = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                              "{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}", date, message);
When disabled:
string output = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {1}", date, message);
```

Это то, что мне нужно. Проблема только в том, что данная галка включена и эффекта, как в описании нет. Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартное сочетание клавиш для включения переноса длинных строк:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>;<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>.

Если не подошли, то откройте в правом углу шестеренку настроек, зайдите в настройки, и в строке поиска наберите "soft wrap".